# Avro serialization: How does the length of keys effect the size of data after serialisation as byte array?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, avro

I created two Avro schemas, one had short keys, and the other hand long keys. I put the same data on them, and the serialised them as `byte array`.
Then, I checked the length, and it was the same.

If it does not effect the size of the data, then how are keys saved?

Schema I tested on:

```
{
"namespace": "namespace",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "TestA",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "dataFieldIsVeryVeryVeryLong", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "dataField2IsVeryVeryVeryVerylong", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null}
     ]
}
```

AND

```
{
"namespace": "namespace",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "TestB",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "s", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "ss", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null}
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys are not saved, avro serialisation works based on types and order of fields. In your case you use:

- record - it's a concatenation of fields
- string is long for length and then UTF-8 encoding of characters
- union of two types, it has int to specify which type it is and then it's using this type encoding

For this value:

```
{
    "s": "qwe",
    "ss": null
}
```

Encoding in hex will be `06  71  77  65  00` - We know it's a record, so we go for fields encoding. First is a string, for a string first is a length, `06` is an avro encoding of long 3, so next 3 values are a string content. If you search for ASCII table with hex values you will see that `71` is q, `77` is w and `65` is e.
Next field is union, so encoding has int for which type, `00` is avro encoding for int 0, so first type in the union. This is "null" in your case, null is encoded as no bytes, so that's the end of the data. If it was `02`, that would mean type on position 1 - string in your schema and it would follow with encoding of string value.

You can read more about it in [documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#binary_encoding)

If you want to see more examples I wrote a [post](https://writeitdifferently.com/avro/binary/encoding/2020/07/26/avro-binary-encoding-in-kafka.html) about it

Comment: So, do we infer that if we store a byte-serialised avro, and store the data somewhere, be it some database or message queue, it will consume less space than something like JSON or JSONString, Map (or basically any key-value paired schema)?

Comment: This is not easy to answer. Binary encoding of value should be smaller, maybe if you used some compression on JSON it could have relatively small size. The question is how you store your schema. If you are using something like a Schema Registry then you will have to store an id (int) with your message. If you decide to store a schema with every message it will take more space. Avro, Protobuf and Thrift offer you schema evolution, which can be beneficial when changing later format of the data. Storage is relatively cheap, especially in comparison with human/maintanace cost.